# What's the quickest way to add an element to a dictionary if it doesn't exist and incrementing the value if it does exist?

Tags: c#

I want the C# equivalent of this C++ code:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> myDictionary;
myDictionary["foo"] += 1;
```

The second line in the C++ code translated to C# (by using a `Dictionary<string, int>`) throws an exception if the element doesn't already exist in the dictionary. This is normal behaviour but wouldn't this code be fairly slow?

```
if (myDictionary.ContainsKey("foo"))
{
    myDictionary["foo"]++;
}
else
{
    myDictionary.Add("foo", 1);
}
```

What I am asking for is, in Dictionary, is there a function that does the equivalent of the above code but faster? Or is this the fastest I can get it to be?

Comment: Have you tried `TryAdd` method? Maybe it is faster?

Comment: In C# you need two lines of code for it. 1st: use `TryGetValue` and 2nd line use `myDictionary["foo"]=value+1`. That's also the most efficient way since you first need to lookup the value before you can create/update it. The duplicate question shows how to do it.

Comment: As for "the fastest" - try looking into `CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrNullRef` as in the second suggested duplicate. But in general would just use the`TryGetValue`.

Comment: According to BenchmarkDotNet the following is 3 times faster than using `ContainsKey()`, at least for the case where the item usually exists in the dictionary: `ref int intRef = ref CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault(_dict, "foo", out bool exists); if (exists) ++intRef; else intRef = 1;`

Comment: If the code would work when initialising the value to `0` rather than `1` you could omit the `else intRef = 1`

Comment: @MatthewWatson Even faster just increment directly `(ref CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault(_dict, "foo", out bool exists))++;`

Comment: The method of using TryGetValue seems to be pretty fast but I'll see the method you provided. Thank you

Comment: @Charlieface To be clear though, that only works if it's OK to initialise the value to 0 (it's initialised to 1 in the OP's code)

Comment: @MatthewWatson No, it's initialized to `0` then unconditionally incremented. So adding the first value always gets you `1` with that code.

Comment: @Charlieface Ah, of course